# How to avoid double foreach in backward relationships in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I am trying to print some variables with these relations:

**The first:**

```html
public function group(){
         return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
     }
```

**The second:**

```html
public function joinGroups(){
         return $this->hasMany(JoinGroup::class);
     }
```

My question is how could I access $group->joinGroups->name_group without doing a double foreach? I must do this that I show you below because the relationships are upside down...

```html
@foreach ($groups as $group)
   @foreach($group->joinGroups as $joinGroups)
      {{$joinGroups->name_group}}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Is there an easier way to avoid the middle foreach? According to what code everything is duplicated.

Comment: You are getting multiple groups at once so of course there are two loops

Comment: Well based on your database struture `group` hasMany `joinGroup`, 2 foreach is necessary for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach ($groups as $group)
   {{$group->joinGroups[0]->name_group}}
@endforeach
```

you can apply the above code if you want to simply access the name_group of index 0, same goes for other index.

Comment: Thanck you bro ;)